# Im just trying to do complete my CW early

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, timer, jframe

I need a timer for my Java project but Im struggling to find one What would I use in Java for a timer (similar to the timer in VB)?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Add an action listener to perform the actions.